# Using form submission to update table records in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a support form for some clients, they submit information to it and I see it in a panel I have created. In this panel I want to have the ability to check a box next to a record and hit an update button and it will update that record with a time stamp showing I have completed the work and what time. Here is the sample code

```
 echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>ICL</th>
<th>PAGE ID</th>
<th>SUBMISSION NAME</th>
<th>UPTDATES/BUGS</th>
<th>MISSING INFO</th>
<th>TIME OF SUBMISSION</th>
<th>COMPLETED</th>
<th>TIME COMPLETED</th>
</tr>";
echo "<form name='completed' action='insert4panel.php' method='post'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($results))
  {
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['ICL'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['officename'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['submitname'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['feedback'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['missinginfo'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['TimeStamp'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='complete'></td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['completionstamp'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
  }
echo "<input type='submit' value='Update'>";
echo "</form>";
echo "</table>";
```

What happens when I hit submit I send it to this code

```
$timeissued=$_POST["complete"];
$date = date("m-d-y H:i:s");
mysql_query("INSERT INTO SITES (completed, completetime )
VALUES ('$timeissued' ,'$date')");
```

I know that I'm not telling it which record I want to add the timestamp or the check box to, so it isn't going to do it, however it creates a new record with a timestamp doesn't save the check box and leaves the rest of the fields blank. I'm sure the answer is simple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your checkbox so that it is a `value=1` attribute.

Change the name of said checkbox to `name=complete[$id]`

Now, on the PHP side of things, do something along the lines of...

```
<?php
$complete = $_POST["complete"];
$time = time();
foreach($complete as $key => $value) {
    $query = "UPDATE SITES
              SET completed=1, completedtime='$time'
              WHERE id = '$key'";
    // This query is not in any way secure...
    mysql_query($query);
}
```

This will loop through ALL of the checkboxes you hit and set the `completed` field in your database to 1, and the `completedtime` field to the current time stamp, which is an integer.

Though, you shouldn't be using mysql_* functions on account of them being deprecated. You should look into PDO.

Comment: I can't get this one to update them in the database I updated the following.
    `<td><input type='checkbox' name='complete[$id]' value='1'</td>`
    `$complete = $_POST["complete"];
      $time = time();`
     `foreach(complete as $key => $value) {
      $query = "UPDATE SITES
              SET completed='1', completedtime='$time'
              WHERE id = '$key'";
    // This query is not in any way secure...
    mysql_query($query);
    }`
it puts a time stamp in of 0000-00-00 but not just on one record on all but the one I checked the box of

Comment: the `time()` method outputs an integer... The number of seconds since the UNIX epoch. PHP's [date](http://php.net/date) method will let you turn the time stamp into an actual date, which is what you can place in your database.

Comment: I just mean, it's not working, it's not updating completed to 1 nor is it creating the time stamp even when I use the date();

Comment: Are you getting any sort of error or warning? echo your sql call and place that into PHPMyAdmin or something similar if you have that available. is your table called `SITES`, or is it called `Sites` or something? SQL is case sensitive.

Comment: its SITES, I checked over everything first to make sure I didn't do anything like that. Everything matches. I get the feeling it has to do with this `echo "<td><input type='checkbox' name='complete[$id]' value='1'></td>";`

Comment: So... I just looked over my code again and I noticed that I missed a $ in the `foreach` method... if you copy/pasted my code, that would be why it wasn't working... also, `print_r($complete);` should help debug a little bit.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17477/discussion-between-user1542036-and-justin-wood)

Comment: ok I got it to work. I changed complete[$id] to complete[" . $row['id'] ."] and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

This is going to be difficult to answer without sounding condescending, so I'll keep it simple:

It's clear you're new to both PHP and database interaction.

It is making a new record because you're telling it to with `("INSERT INTO...")`
You should be using `("UPDATE`sites`SET...")`. see reference here:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp

Look into PDO and discontinue all mysql_ functions. see reference:
http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php

You can give your checkbox a value of the record ID so the DB knows which to update. Also, you need to name the input with an array:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="complete[]" value="<?php echo $row['id']; ?>">
```

That way you can iterate through all set checkboxes on post and update all records checked.

I don't know how to properly explain all of this without launching into a tutorial on how to write PHP and interact with databases. The reference links should be enough to get started.

If you have specific questions feel free to ask. I will update my answer accordingly